# How to automate Windows installation process?

Tags: installation, automation, windows-installation

If I want to install OpenSuse/SUSE on more laptops/workstations and let them all have the same configuration, or even just save the current configuration for one workstation just so that I may reinstall later, I can use a tool called autoyast. Is there such thing in the Windows realm?

Comment: If you want to install OpenSuse/SUSE why are you asking about installing Windows unattended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mutlitple options available. Depends on your company size, your it staff and the $$$ you want to pay. But to help you on your way.

1. Install windows
2. Make changes / install programs
3. Boot machine using sysprep
4. Use sysprep to generalize your installation
5. Copy wim

For a complete guide follow [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523217(v=ws.10).aspx)

other options include installing a [Windows deployment server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg293118.aspx)

Comment: As davejal pointed out, there are many, many options for deploying Windows.

Keep it simple and use the Microsoft recommended method and solution, the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit. It is also free. See the guides here on TechNet:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt297535

I also recommend checking out the Surface Pro 3 Deployment and Administration Guide, which provides a thorough look at Windows deployment from the ground up:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45292